# Excel - how to hide value in a chart's datalebel

Tags: excel, series

I have embedded an image to a chart's datalabel. I want to only keep the image and not the value which appears on top of the image.

However I'm not sure how i can get rid of the value to only show the image?

I thought could've set the font colour to transparent but that's not available. I also played around with the number formatter but had no luck?

I'm using Windows/Excel 2010

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on one of the data labels once will select all of them, clicking a second time will select only the one you clicked on. Then just hit the delete button. (You should also be able to edit the font/colour in the Home tab.)

Comment: Sorry I believe you may have misunderstood what I'm trying to do. I want to keep the datalabel but I only want the image inside the datalabel not the value which appears on top.

Comment: OK, but double-clicking on the datalabel should bring up a text editing menu, on which you can delete or change the colour of the text? Works for me on Excel 2010.

Comment: Double clicking and deleting the value resizes the image.